# Purple sky in Spore

Tags: spore

I just playing Spore, and I'm on the Creature Stage. Don't know why, but I have purple sky. I watched let's plays, most of players have blue sky, but some have purple too. Question is: is purple sky normal? Can I change it to blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different planets have different colors; most of them unorthodox.

Your planet has a purple sky instead of a blue one. Another example would be having red water instead of blue water.

You can preview a planet before starting on a new game on it.